# Get search video from YouTube Data API?

Tags: jquery, youtube-api

I am using youtube data API and wanted to display the searched videos  , but it is having some issue, please someone solve my issue, Thanks in Advance,below is my jquery code

```
             $(function () {


             var searchField = $("#query");
             var icon = $("#search-btn");



             $("#search-form").submit(function (e) {
                 e.preventDefault();
             });
         }); /**Document**/

         function search() {
             $("#results").html("");
             $("#buttons").html("");

             var q = $("#query").val();

             //Run GET request on API

             $.get("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/search", {
                     part: 'snippet, id',
                     q: q,
                     type: 'video',
                     key: 'AIzaSyBj7R8zsjiyc1durQHNZcZyb5KkwnbhdMc'
                 },
                 function (data) {
                     var nextPageToken = data.nextPageToken;
                     var prevPageToken = data.prevPageToken;
                     console.log(data);

                 }
             );

         }
```

Comment: "I have an issue" doesn't describe the problem. What does your error log say?  What's not working?

Comment: Their is no error showing in console,thats why i am stuck nothing is showing..thanks for the reply

Comment: Since you're using GET method, check if you are getting a null response or not.

Comment: You forgot to mention the version, URL should read `https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search`